# How to redirect to a URL with variable in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I think I am stuck with something very basic and I would like an answer...
In flask app, I want to 1) Grab the input from the user, 2) do some processing with the input, and 3) return the result to the same URL as step 1).

```
<form action="/api" method="POST">
    <input name="userinput"></input>
    <button type="submit">Start process</button>
</form>
    <ul>
      {% for result in output %}
        <li>
          {{result}}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

```
@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    return render_template("foo.html", output="")


@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def some_process():
    user_input = request.form['userinput']
    output = someprocess(user_input) // returns an array
    return render_template("foo.html", output=output)
```

This works, but with this code, the URL is stuck with `/api` in the Step 3). I want to make it `/foo`.

I tried using `redirect()`, but it doesn't allow me to pass arguments (in this case `output`)
I also tried using redirect with `url_for`, but when I did `return redirect(url_for("foo", output=output))`, the `output` was all in the URL path and that was not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the result should be displayed on the same page as the input form.
Since the form will be submitted via POST, you can define an endpoint that accepts both GET and POST. Within you can then use the request object to distinguish which method was used.

```py
@app.route('/foo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    output = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_input = request.form['userinput']
        output = someprocess(user_input) // returns an array
    return render_template('foo.html', output=output)
```

```
<form method="POST">
    <input name="userinput" />
    <button type="submit">Start process</button>
</form>

<ul>
  {% for result in output %}
    <li>
      {{result}}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```