# Flask Redirect to Variable URL

Tags: javascript, python, flask, redirect, routes

I am trying to redirect users to a different url based on some form data they input.
Here is the idea.
User fills out `blahblah.com/Page-1` with answer1 and answer2.

I am using Flask with this too, but yeah for some reason the page wont redirect on submit

I created some js code like this to try and handle that:

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var family_name = document.getElementById('answer1').value;
  var invite_code = document.getElementById('answer2').value;

  console.log(answer1, answer2);

  var redirectUrl = `/rsvp/${encodeURIComponent(answer1)}/${answer2}`;
  window.location.href = redirectUrl;
});
```

On `submit`, I want them to be `redirected` to `blahblah.com/Page-2/answer1/answer2`

It is extremely similar to this other post, [How to redirect to a URL with variable in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76906324/how-to-redirect-to-a-url-with-variable-in-flask), except I want to redirect to a different page.

Would I just do something like what they had?

```
@app.route('/page-2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page-2():
    output = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_input = request.form['userinput']
        output = someprocess(user_input) // returns an array
    return render_template('page-2.html', answer1=answer1)
`
```

Do I need to have a separate route for `/Page-2/answer1/answer2` ?
Sorry I'm a Flask noob haha

Comment: I don't think you need JavaScript to achieve your goal. However, the actual objective is still unclear to me. You want to send input to the server and present a result on a separate page. Should the form data be sent in the URL (GET), visible to the user and third parties, or in the request body (POST)? The solution to be chosen depends on this decision.

Comment: To be more transparent, here is what is going on behind the scenes:
I am using the url to get the family and invite codes. Then with the invite code, I will extract the family's guests from a separate db. (no I am not technically using the family code yet)

`
@app.route('/rsvp/<family_name>/<invite_code>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def rsvp(family_name, invite_code):
    # Fetch the list of guests from the database based on the invite code
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT guests FROM users WHERE invite_code=?", (invite_code,))
`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to achieve your goal is to use one endpoint for the form, which forwards to a second one when the form data is entered successfully.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="family-name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="family-name" id="family-name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="invite-code">Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="invite-code" id="invite-code" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```py
from flask import redirect, render_template, request, url_for

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        family_name = request.form['family-name']
        invite_code = request.form['invite-code']
        return redirect(url_for('rsvp', family_name=family_name, invite_code=invite_code))
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/rsvp/<string:family_name>/<string:invite_code>') 
def rsvp(family_name, invite_code): 

    # ...

    return render_template('rsvp.html', **locals())
```

An alternative solution is to use a form with a GET method instead of [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#variable-rules), which sends the data as URL parameters directly to the second endpoint. Since the parameters are optional, it is then your job to check whether they were sent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ url_for('rsvp') }}" method="GET">
        <div>
            <label for="family-name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="family-name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="invite-code">Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="code" id="invite-code" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```py
from flask import abort, render_template, request

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/rsvp')
def rsvp():
    family_name = request.args.get('name')
    invite_code = request.args.get('code')
    if not family_name and not invite_code:
        abort(404)

    # ...

    return render_template('rsvp.html', **locals())
```